# How to make Sweet alert auto close after ajax complete?

Tags: php, ajax, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm using sweet alert, but i want make it close automatically if the request of ajax is completed

```
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "You are choosing order by custom search",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
  confirmButtonText: "Confirm",
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  timer: **AUTO WITH AJAX??**
},
```

I am adding a variable

```
var dones = $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
                            swal.close()
                        });
```

and make swal like this

```
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "You are choosing order by custom search",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
  confirmButtonText: "Confirm",
  **timer: dones,**
  closeOnConfirm: false
},
```

but still not like I expected

Comment: Are you sure you are entering your `.ajaxComplete` callback function? I've never seen that before so I'm assuming it's something special. Anyway, put an `alert()` or a `console.log()` in there to make sure your code even gets there, yeah? Then come back to me. swal.close() should work perfectly fine. Also, your question is quite confusing. What is it you want? The timer, or the ajax call closing it?

Comment: Please post your ajax code.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend you to use [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) - the supported fork of original SweetAlert.

What you looking for is `onOpen` parameter and `.showLoading()` method, here's your task:

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'I will close automatically when AJAX request is finished',
  didOpen: function () {
    Swal.showLoading()
    // AJAX request simulated with setTimeout
    setTimeout(function () {
      Swal.close()
    }, 2000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

PS. notice that SweetAlert2 is a little bit different from SweetAlert, check the simple migration guide: https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/wiki/Migration-from-SweetAlert-to-SweetAlert2

Answer (score 0):

After ajax success function just trigger a time out function

```
setTimeout(function () {
    Swal.close()
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

for me I always do like that.I hope someone will get help :).

```
      <script>
       Swal.showLoading()
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajax_obj.ajax_url,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                action: "your_action",
                security: ajax_obj.nonce,
                form_data: eiFormData
            },
            success: function (response) {
                swal.close()
            }
        })
      </script>
```