# Best way to use ajaxstop with sweetalert2

Tags: jquery, ajax, sweetalert2

I do several ajax calls and would like to do the final swal fire once all ajax calls are done.
I tried that in the code below, but obviously, it doesn't have the desired effect. Basically, what I would like is that, after the text are displayed "All Done.... Success!", I would like to have the showLoaderOnConfirm: true option while the ajaxStop function is running
my present crappy code:

```
Swal.fire(
'All done!',
'I will now analyse your answers. Just give me a second',
'success',
).then(function() {
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
//do other stuff here like... form submit, etc. once all Ajax calls are done
$('#myform_id').submit();
});
})
```

What happens in the above code is that the Swal dialog is closed, and at least one of my ajax calls are still running before #myformid is submitted, with the user wondering what is happening

Many thanks in advance, to help a newbie out!
Regards
Rajan

Answer (score 0):

After searching high and low... found what I was looking for. Did a bit of a change from what is mentioned at [How to make Sweet alert auto close after ajax complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48877076/how-to-make-sweet-alert-auto-close-after-ajax-complete)

My changed code:

```
Swal.fire({
  title: 'I will close automatically when AJAX request is finished',
  onOpen: function () {
    Swal.showLoading()



                $( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
                    $('#myformid).submit();
                    Swal.close()
                });

  }
})
```